# Moodle 4.1.2 giving issue with boost theme

Tags: moodle, moodle-boost

Moodle 4.1.2 giving issue with boost theme

Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(a,b,c){"use strict";function d(a,b){if(!(a instanceof b))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}function e(a){var b=a.getBoundingClientRect(),c={};for(var d in b)c[d]=b[d];if(a.ownerDocument!==document

Any help please?

Comment: Please share more details. What's the "issue" you are facing? What have you tried to resolve it?